# Python process suspended despite running caffeinate

Tags: terminal, sleep-wake, python

**UPDATE**: since updating to macOS 10.14 this issue is not occurring to me anymore.

I have a long running Python process (using multiprocessing), run from Terminal, and regularly come back to it realizing that it has been suspended for several hours while I was away from the Mac. The moment I get back to it it's running again at normal speed (it's displaying a progress bar in Terminal). This is despite:

- checking "prevent computer from going to sleep automatically when the display is off" in the Energy Saver preferences panel
- running `caffeinate` from the parent process (`Popen('caffeinate')`), which does show up in the Energy section of Activity Monitor
- Using appnope to begin an activity with `NSActivityUserInitiated | NSActivityLatencyCritical`

This happens on multiple Computers, but has only started happening recently, i.e. I don't think it occurred before 10.13.

Why could this be occurring, and what other means are there to investigate or prevent it?

Comment: Not sure what's going wrong despite running `caffeinate` command. Installing and running a dedicated app that prevents the Mac from sleeping does the trick for me. You can give KeepingYouAwake Menu Bar app (https://github.com/newmarcel/KeepingYouAwake) a try and see if that resolves your problem.

Comment: I don't think the computer is going to sleep – I suspect it might be App Nap. I am trying whether `appnope` helps.

Comment: Have you had any luck with appnope?

Comment: I won't know until I leave the computer alone for a while :) , I will report back

Comment: I suspect the reason was that I designated my processes as daemon. Since I removed that designation I haven’t seen the issue.

Comment: I was too quick. The suspension still happens, even when I don't use multiprocessing and begin an activity with `NSActivityUserInitiated | NSActivityLatencyCritical`. Activity monitor (Energy tab) does say that idle sleep is prevented for the main process.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this seems to have solved itself and can't be reproduced